# What's the difference between dots and asterik in Perforce mapping rules?

Tags: perforce

I understand that `//depot/foo/...` will map all the files and folders under `//depot/foo/`. So, what does `//depot/foo/*` do? I was told not to use it, and would like to understand why.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`...` recurses, `*` does not.  If you want to match all files at a given location and all files below that location, you use `...`; if you want to match only files in a given folder, use `*`.

With your example

- `//depot/foo/*` will only match files
  in the 'foo' folder (if there are
  any)
- `//depot/foo/...` will match files
  in the foo folder as well as any
  files beneath foo

For simple client specs, you want to use `...` so that you get all files in all subdirectories in a depot.  You might use the `*` character in a clientspec when you want to match files in a specific folder and nothing underneath.  As an example

```
//depot/foo/...  //myclient/depot/foo/...
-//depot/foo/test/... //myclient/depot/foo/test/...
//depot/foo/test/* //myclient/depot/foo/test/*
```

The above will (in order), add all files in the //depot/foo location.  Then it will remove everything in //depot/foo/test (including files in the test folder).  The third line will then add back in *just* the files in the test folder and nothing underneath.